# Get content of RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs object

Tags: c#, wpf

I am returning a `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` object and I'm trying to get the error number which I can see in the object. When I use `if (err.Number!= 2627){}` I get the following error

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Number' and no extension
>   method 'Number' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please can someone advise how I can get the objects contents (see immediate window below).

Also please can someone explain what is actually happening here as the error indicates the object does not contain a definition for 'Number' but it looks like it does exist?

**CODE:**

```
private void GBHworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
             RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //update UI once worker complete his work 
    if (e.Result != null)
    {
        var err = e.Result;
        if (err.Number!= 2627) //don't want to raise error on duplicate primary key
        {
            MessageBoxButton btn = MessageBoxButton.OK;
            var result = ModernDialog.ShowMessage(e.Result.ToString(), 
                         "Error", btn);
        }
    }
}
```

**ASSIGNING e:**

```
private void GBHworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

  //....DB parameter setup
  try
  {
    cmd_insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  catch (Exception crap)
  {
    if (e != null)
      e.Result = crap;
  }

 }
```

**IMMEDIATE WINDOW:**

```
?err
{"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_XYZ'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.XYZ. The duplicate key value is (30527293868).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
    base {System.Data.Common.DbException}: {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_XYZ'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.XYZ'. The duplicate key value is (30527293868).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
    Class: 14
    ClientConnectionId: {*******}
    Errors: {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection}
    LineNumber: 1
    Number: 2627
    Procedure: ""
    Server: "*******"
    Source: ".Net SqlClient Data Provider"
    State: 1
```

Comment: Result is defined as object, so that's why you can't see a Number property on it. You need to cast it first.

Comment: You need to cast it to the type you are assigning e.  You need to post the code where you are assigning e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about casting `e.Result` to `DbException`?

```
var exp=e.Result as DbException;

if(exp!=null){
    //NOW USE IT: exp.Number;
}
```

`Result` is of type `Object`

EDIT:- If you remove **try/catch** in `_DoWork` as @Habib has suggested, then use following code as he has illustrated:

```
var err=e.Error as SqlException;
if(err!=null && err.Number ==2627)
{
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Result` property to get exception details, instead use [`Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error.aspx) property and since you are expecting an `SqlException`, cast the `Error` to `SqlException`, then you can check the `Number`

```
if (e.Error != null)
{
   var error = e.Error as SqlException;
   if(eror != null && error.Number == 2627)
     {
      //duplicate key
     }
}
```

Currently you are getting the error because `e.Result` is of type `Object`, you have to cast it to particular type to access its properties.

Comment: This isn't working for me here as `e.Error` always returns null for me? Am I assigning e correctly? (I've added the _DoWork code)

Comment: @ooo, remove exception handling from `DoWork`, if any exception occur, it will be available in `e.Error`, also check for e.Cancelled and e.Error before accessing e.Result.